# Why is there no error being reported when I send a score to a GC leaderboard that does not exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, game-center, gamekit

My Game Center game, upon authentication, for testing I am sending a score to a leaderboard that clearly does not exist in my iTunes Connect page:

```
// Successful authentication here
[self reportScore:1000 forLeaderboardID:@"blah blah blah blah"];
```

And here's the method:

```
-(void)reportScore:(int64_t)score forLeaderboardID:(NSString*)category {
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error == NULL) {
            NSLog(@"Score sent successfully");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Score submission failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

I am getting

> Score sent successfully

Why? I definitely don't have such leaderboard in my game.

Some facts:

- My game is of course in iTunes Connect
- Game Center seems to work in general. I can make multiplayer matches just fine.
- The game has no achievements.
- The game is in sandbox mode.
- I am authenticated with a test user.
- The game in iTunes Connect does have one leaderboard, but definitely not the one I'm referring to in the code above.
- Using iOS 7 on an iPhone 5.